# Returning a value through dispatching in Zend

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, dispatch

I'm new to Zend frameWork. im testing an action ,that returns a boolean, through dispatching:

```
 $this->dispatch('/album/action', 'POST', $postData);
```

the Question is how can I get the return Value of this action, as i want to assert it is true?
Thanks.

Comment: are you accessing album action from another controller or in same controller ?

Comment: in the same controller

Answer (score 0):

so you dont need to use dispatch

use this

```
$yourValue = $this->action($postData);
```

Comment: sorry, i miss understood your question then. I'm calling to test the action from a TestController Class. to write your code I have to make a new object from the Controller class, which is something i don't want to do, plus the action doesn't take parameters. Thank you for replying.